# Division of two polynomial expressions

Tags: polynomials, computer-algebra-systems

Is $$1/(X^n - 1), n \in N$$ a polynomial?

Intuitively I would say yes, because 1 is a polynomial($ X^0$) and so is $X^n - 1$. But Sage (The CAS) appears to disagree, when I type the expression in and call the function `is_polynomial()` I get False. Can somebody explain why this expression isn't a polynomial?

Comment: $x^n-1$ is a polynomial, but $1/(x^n-1)$ is not; likewise, $7$ is an integer but $1/7$ is not

Comment: No, it is not a polynomial. It is a rational function, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) in $x$ are defined as a finite sum of terms of the form $ax^n$.  $a$ is restricted to some set like the integers, rationals, reals, integers $\bmod $ something, complex numbers.  $n$ is restricted to the nonnegative integers.  Rational functions of polynomials do not count, so Sage is correct.

Comment: The task I had is to simplify a very specific q-binomial coefficient, and to check if it could be simplified to a polynomial expression. After I coded the needed functions and simplified I got something like $\frac{1}{\prod_{i = 1}^{n}(q^i - 1)}$ and this is apparently not a polynomial. You could take a look at my comment on the answer below to see what I exactly mean. Also, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a *rational fraction*, i.e. the quotient of two polynomials in the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $K[X]$ ($K$ is the field of coefficients, which you did not specify). This field of fractions is denoted
$K(X).$

Comment: $K$ could be any generic ring, I don't see why that matters. The original task I had is to analyse if the q-binomial coefficient ${n \choose m}_{q} = {\frac{[n]_{q}}{[m]_{q} \cdot [n - m]_{q}}}$, with $ [n]_{q} = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} (1 - q^i)$ could be simplified to a polynomial expression. After i coded the functions and simplified i got something like $\frac{1}{\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (q^i - 1)}$. So I guess the answer is no. This specific q-binomial coefficient could not be simplified to a polynomial expression.

Comment: This depends on what is $q$  and in which ring it lives.  Furthermore, a polynomial function is not the same object as a polynomial. You should have explained the context. And a polynomial ring dies not always have a field of fractions – the coefficient ring has to be a domain.

Comment: $q$ is a variable `var('q')` in the Sage notation, but if you're asking about the exact type of $q$, it's an element of a symbolic ring. And sorry I forgot to mention, i'm supposed to check this only for $1 \leq m \leq n \leq 10$ and not for every $n,m \in N$.

Comment: Symbolic Ring: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/ring.html

Comment: Yeah, i messed up at explaining what I really want. Sorry.